# jQuery: Auto-hide notification when it's visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id="messages">
<div class="message"> <!-- Visible (5 seconds for hide, show the next, and hide again) -->
<div class="message" style="display:none;"> <!-- Hidden -->
<div class="message" style="display:none;"> <!-- Hidden -->
</div>
```

The following (noob) code will hide the `<div>` tag after five seconds of be created, so I want to hide each notification after five seconds but when it's visible, It's something like a slideshow but with notifications, 5 seconds per notification when it's visible.

```
function setid() {
    $('.message').each(function() {
        if($(this).attr('id')==uniqID) { 
            uniqID = Math.floor(Math.random()*9999999);
        }
    });
}

console.log = function(message) {
    console.olog(message);
    setid();
    $('#messages').append('<div id="' + uniqID + '" class="message"> + message + '</div>').show();
    $('#' + uniqID).slideDown(200).delay(5000).slideUp(200);
};
```

Comment: Carful with single/double quotes. This won't work `$('#messages').append('<div id="' + uniqID + '" class="message"> + message + '</div>').show();` See the hint in the code highlighting? That should tell you something is wrong.

Comment: class="message">' Yes, sorry, I always write it wrong in the example code, I did it carefully but I did't see that. Thanks.

Comment: You should fix the code then. Also what's this `console.log = function(action,message)`??. And this `console.olog(message);`?

Comment: @elclanrs Yes. sorry, I am using the "action" in my dev code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually very simple:

```
$(".message").hide().first().show();
setTimeout(showNotifications, 5000);
function showNotifications(){
    $(".message:visible").remove();
    $(".message").first()show();
    if($(".message").length > 0){
        setTimeout(showNotifications, 5000);
    }
}
```

How it works:
It selects all the `.message` elements and hide them except the first one.
After 5 seconds, the first message will be removed from the webpage and the following message will be shown for another 5 seconds and this goes until there is no more notification messages in the site.

**Want some animations as well?** Check out this:

```
$(".message").hide().first().show('slow');
setTimeout(showNotifications, 5000);
function showNotifications(){
    $(".message:visible").hide('slow', function(){
        $(this).remove();
        $(".message").first().show('slow');
        if($(".message").length > 0){
           setTimeout(showNotifications, 5000);
        }
    });
}​
```

[**Click here for a working example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/tgbzQ/)

Comment: **Papaiatis** I suggest you cache `$(".message")` for performance. Also, `$(".message:first")` is way slower than `$(".message").first()`

Comment: @elclanrs `first()` was a good point but caching `$(".message")` requires more maintenance and code because you need to remove the selected elements from the cached array and from the DOM as well. Of course I agree with you about performance, but if I can afford to keep it simple then I'll do so.

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean by _remove the selected elements from the cached array and from the DOM_? Caching elements will make code easier to maintain and in this example there's no reason not to do it.

Comment: It's fixed, I can't edit my post, I will try to add the answer when the time it's finished, thanks to all!

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this.

```
var intervalId, 
    $messages = $('#messages').find('.messages:visible'), 
    count = 0;

$messages.hide();//hide all the messages 

$messages.eq(count).show();//show the first message

intervalId = setInterval(function(){
   $messages.eq(count).hide();//hide the previous message
   if(count < $messages.length){
       $messages.eq(++count).show();//show the next message     
   }
   else{//all the messages are over clear the interval
       clearInterval(intervalId);
   }
}, 5000);
```